# Python pyramid force download without opening file in browser

Tags: python, pyramid

I want to implement force in python pyramid framework when a request come like

> example.com/media/files/test.mp3
>   it open in the browser and start running. i want to stop it and make it forcefully download.

Comment: Please show us some code. Otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Please include an interrogative sentence in your post.

Comment: First i tried this way  [http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/static_assets/files.html] and it does not work for me for force download

Answer (score 3):

I just working this way and it work for me force download i send file name request parameter

```
@view_config(route_name='download')
def download_view(request):
    MEDIA_PATH= os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media'),
    if request.params.get('filename', ''):
        filename = request.params['filename']
        file_path = MEDIA_PATH + filename
        base_file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)           
   response = FileResponse(file_path, request=request,cache_max_age=86400)
   headers = response.headers
   headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/download'
   headers['Accept-Ranges'] = 'bite'
   headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=' +base_file_name
   return response
```

add this view in init.py

> config.add_route('download', '/download')

send file name parameter it work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `download="test.mp3"` to the download link.

So it would be like:

```
<a href="example.com/media/files/test.mp3" download="test.mp3">Download Now</a>
```